# Blender Function need help

Tags: edit-mode, transforms

I found this guys on YouTube he able to move the object on *edit mode* by <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> on spaces and move the vertex. But when I try on my own blender because I'm curious it just make a select box not moving the object. Here are the picture to show what I mean

[image]

From the picture above it shows that he click the outer range but able to move the vertex of the apple and he uses *proportional editing* that is why he can move all around the vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the Youtube tutorial I can only suppose what exactly the guy is doing, but I'm quite sure he has the *Move* tool enabled (the cross of arrows on the left) while you probably have the default *Select* tool enabled (which is the cursor in a box on the top left). If you enable the *Move* tool, left-click a vertex to select it, then left-click and drag the selected vertex while holding the mouse button. And with *Proportional Editing* enabled, the other vertices will be affected, too.

**//EDIT:** In the default settings for (newer) versions of Blender, you have to click and drag the selected vertex. What is missing in the tutorial (it's for Blender 2.8), is a selectable option for how to use *Drag* with the mouse (see last image at the top): by default it's set to *Select Box*. If you switch this to *Active Tool*, you can click somewhere in the viewport and start dragging the vertex.

[image: select tools]

[image: drag vertex]

[image: active tool]

Comment: here is the Link of the Yt  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEVAGnR2GRQ&list=PL3UWN2F2M2C8-zUjbFlbgtWPQa0NXBsp0&index=7 and its on minute of 13:06

Comment: i mean he moved the vertex tho from the outer spaces

Comment: @VincentThamrin Yeah, I guess you are using a different Blender version than Zach does in the tutorial (he's on 2.8), in newer versions you can change the option for dragging. I've edited the answer to show where you change it.

Comment: yeah,im using the latest version i think i use Blender that download on Steam

Comment: @VincentThamrin The problem is, most of the time and especially for really basic tutorials it doesn't matter that much which version you are using. But some features are not the same in each version, so you might keep an eye on that if something doesn't work as expected. Unfortunately not all tutorials are available for each version. Anyway, the edit I made to the answer should fix your problem.

Comment: so what you need to do is just change the Drag from  Select box to Active tools ? cuz mine i think is select box.

Comment: That's what I wrote... _Select Box_ is the default setting. I didn't watch the tutorial, I have no idea if he changed anything. But in his older version you cannot even see the option on top of the window so maybe it worked like that by default back then.